# How to automate opening a file in file explorer

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

In my automation tests, there are two upload links (in different test scopes) that open the windows file explorer automatically.  The problem I have is that I need to be able to open two different files depending on the page, and they are located in different directories.  When the second link is clicked, the file explorer is opened to the location of the first file, and then my tests fail because the file I'm looking for does not exist there.

This there a way (using Java) that I can navigate to a (nearly) completely different file path with automaton?  My current method is using the Robot class to copy and paste the file names into the "File Name" field of file explorer.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837367/upload-file-via-window-prompt-in-selenium-webdriver-using-autoit#) [this](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit) and [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: which browser your using?

Comment: @Ant's I'm primarily using Chrome, but I have to expand my tests to include IE and Firefox